# media player should stop on disconnecting headphone in my android app programatically

Tags: android, media-player

I have an issue in developing a media  player application.
I want it so that when I remove my headphone from my device then the MediaPlayer in my app pauses.

Comment: Improved some grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android documentation suggests using the AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY intent filter

Set the intent filter in your manafest and then:

```
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override 
   public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
          // signal your service to stop playback 
          // (via an Intent, for instance) 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#noisyintent

Comment: Hi @VishwaPratap that's good to hear. Please make sure you click the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: For some reason, I receive the intent only after a few seconds after the headset disconnection..

Comment: Sorry, it's because I used not AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY for intent-filter.

Comment: Found this link for the guide from the android documentation: 
[Handling changes in audio output](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones#becoming-noisy)

Answer (score 2):

Register Broadcast in same Activity.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mNoisyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if( mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
};
```

Handles headphones coming unplugged. cannot be done through a manifest receiver

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
       registerReceiver(mNoisyReceiver, filter);
    }
```

UnRegister Receiver

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mNoisyReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) Intent over the Broadcast when ever someone Plugs a Headset in or out.

At the start of your App you can use AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() to check if ther is a headset pluged in at the moment. (Dont forgget to add MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission.)